# Python cssselect div, у которого остутствует класс

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, lxml, cssselect

Имеется html:

```
<div id ="search_result_container">
    <div class="search_rule"></div>
    <div>.....</div>
    <div class="search_pagination">......</div>
</div>
```

Необходимо вытащить div, у которого нет класса

Пытаюсь вытащить:

```
div_item = search_result_container.cssselect('div:not([class])')
```

Но он выдает все div-потомки, а мне необходимо искать только среди потомков 1 уровня. Как сделать?

Полностью мой код:

```
import lxml.html

def get_html(request):
    return lxml.html.fromstring(request.text)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    r = request(url)
    html = get_html(r)

    left_panel = html.cssselect('div.leftcol')[0]
    search_result_container = left_panel.cssselect('#search_result_container > div')
    print(search_result_container)
```

Comment: Похоже, lxml делает поиск не с текущего элемента, а с начала всего документа, поэтому при построении запроса укажите с какого элемента искать div без атрибута class. Для css-selector'ов не знаю можно ли указывать что поиск будет локальный, но для xpath это возможно

Comment: вы не поняли, я ищу с определенного контейнера (search_result_container), и он ищет среди всех потомков этого элемента

Comment: почему не понял? я ведь в комментарии предположил почему у вас не работает, а в ответе написал какой вариант сработает, к тому же, у вас тот контейнер с `id`, а значит он один такой на весь HTML документ, поэтому не вижу ничего плохого в полном указании поиска в css-селекторе

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно попробовать такой вариант:

```
html = """\
<div id ="search_result_container">
    <div class="search_rule"></div>
    <div>.....</div>
    <div class="search_pagination">......</div>
</div>
"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
root = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

# Получение соседнего div'а
div = root.select_one('#search_result_container > .search_rule ~ div')
print(div)  # <div>.....</div>

# По индексу:
div = root.select('#search_result_container > div')[1]
print(div)  # <div>.....</div>

# Фильтрация по наличию атрибута class
div_list = [div for div in root.select('#search_result_container > div') if not div.has_attr('class')]
div = div_list[0]
print(div)  # [<div>.....</div>]
```

---

Что-то я не сразу заметил что вопрос был про [lxml](/questions/tagged/lxml), поэтому исправляюсь:

```
from lxml import etree
root = etree.fromstring(html)


def to_str(x):
    return etree.tounicode(x, method='html')


# Получение соседнего div'а
div = root.cssselect('#search_result_container > .search_rule ~ div')[0]
print(to_str(div))  # <div>.....</div>

# Получение соседнего div'а через псевдокласс
div = root.cssselect('#search_result_container > div:nth-child(2)')[0]
print(to_str(div))  # <div>.....</div>

# По индексу:
div = root.cssselect('#search_result_container > div')[1]
print(to_str(div))  # <div>.....</div>

# Фильтрация по наличию атрибута class
div_list = [div for div in root.cssselect('#search_result_container > div') if 'class' not in div.attrib]
div = div_list[0]
print(to_str(div))  # <div>.....</div>

# Фильтрация по наличию атрибута class через псевдокласс
div = root.cssselect('#search_result_container > div:not([class])')[0]
print(to_str(div))  # <div>.....</div>
```

Comment: в метках указал=)

Comment: ага, я не **сразу** это увидел

Comment: я не использую entree, код добавил. В данный момент он выводит все div- потомки 1 уровня

Comment: все, сделал так: search_result_container = left_panel.cssselect('#search_result_container > div:not([class])')

Comment: А чем вам помешает entree? разве элементы из `lxml.html.fromstring` и `etree.fromstring` разные?

Comment: а ну да, затупил

Comment: ага, я вот тоже с BeautifulSoup затупил :D Если мой ответ вас устроил, отметьте его решенным :)

Comment: Не подскажите, как выполнять только поиск до тех пор, пока не нашелся первый элемент. Как я понимаю поиск элемента, например,(html.cssselect('div.leftcol')[0]). происходит так: мы ищем этот элемент по всему дереву. Если мы знаем что такой элемент 1, то зачем мы будем продолжать искать такой же элемент во всем дереве, ведь на это тратится время, нет?

Comment: И да, не подскажите еще более быстрые способы парсинга? Сейчас использую связку lxml+request+concurrent.futures для многопоточности, но думаю можно еще быстрее парсить данные

Comment: Посмотрите в моем ответе строку `:nth-child` мне кажется она как раз и ограничит поиск до одного элемента. А по поводу ускорения, нужно сначала понять что нужно оптимизировать.

Comment: Эта команда указывает номер дочернего элемента. В частности оно конечно вернет 1 элемент, но в других случаях я не могу использовать эту команду, например если буду искать среди всех потомков, а не только среди потомков первого уровня. Что-то нужно вроде аналога в Beautiful Soup (find - ищет и находит только 1 подходящий элемент, а find_all уже ищет все элементы

Comment: `:nth-child — это псевдокласс, который позволяет выбирать элементы по их порядковому номеру` поэтому он применяется к элементам, а не к детям. Поэтому `'#search_result_container > div:nth-child(2)'` вернул второй div в `search_result_container`

Comment: Я понимаю, но порядок этого элемента на разных страницах может меняться, поэтому применение этой команды не возможно

Comment: Я же говорю о том, как найти определенный элемент (один) и прекратить поиск. (Как раз find в Beautiful находил первый подходящий элемент, и дальше не искал)

Comment: кст, cssselect все-равно трансформирует запрос в xpath, мб тогда у xpath посмотреть что-то подходящее, мб использование итератора?

Comment: Я что-то в xpath не припомню такой же функции, всегда делал в результате списка  - [0], чтобы выбрать первый элемент, но это все равно после поиска делалось, на что тратится время, как я думаю

Comment: в selenium webdriver тоже есть разделение на поиск всех элементов, либо поиск одного элемента, а вот в cssselect и xpath такого что-то не видел